# RxJS concat not executing observables sequentially

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have three RxJS observables which I want to execute sequentially. The second Observable should not start executing until the first Observable has finished.

Here's my simplified RxJS code.

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3]

const obs$ = nums.map(num => {
  const promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(num), 2000))
  return rxjs.from(promise)
})

rxjs.concat(...obs$).subscribe(
  num => { console.log('next', num) },
  err => { console.error('error', err.message) },
  () => { console.log('complete') }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

This is the expected output with expected timings:

```
next 1 (at 2 secs)
next 2 (at 4 secs)
next 3 (at 6 secs)
complete (at 6 secs)
```

This is the actual output with actual timings:

```
next 1 (at 2 secs)
next 2 (at 2 secs)
next 3 (at 2 secs)
complete (at 2 secs)
```

As you can see, the timings are not as expected. How do I correct this so that the Observables execute sequentially? Note that there could be X number of Observables such that a solution for exactly three Observables is not acceptable.

Note the setTimeout in my simplified code is not there in real life. This is just mimicking an async op (i.e. an HTTP call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue at hand is actually about the Observable. Concat works as expected by subscribing in order. We only need to create the Observable in a way which will only fire the HTTP call (or any other code) when it is subscribed to. The defer function help with that: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/defer

When we use Angular's HTTP Client, then this is not an issue, since it also defers the execution of the call until the actual subscription.

To demonstrate the correct order of execution, I added another console.log which inside the Observable.

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3]

const obs$ = nums.map(num => {
  return rxjs.defer(() => {
      console.log('order', num);
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(num), 2000 - 500 * num))
  })
})

rxjs.concat(...obs$).subscribe(
  num => { console.log('next', num) },
  err => { console.error('error', err.message) },
  () => { console.log('complete') }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This looks awesome :) many thanks Timothy - a great end to the week :) I'll have a play with this but based on your logs it looks like exactly what I need - will accept now - BTW sadly, although I am using Angular, I am not using Angular's HTTP client but instead am using some twisted firebase functions method of HTTP comms, which is probably why I am experiencing the issue - very thankful for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index` in the map as a second parameter and multiply it with the `setTimeout` timer.

You can do like:

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3]

const obs$ = nums.map((num, i) => {
  const promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(num), 2000*i))
  return rxjs.from(promise)
})

rxjs.concat(...obs$).subscribe(
  num => { console.log('next', num) },
  err => { console.error('error', err.message) },
  () => { console.log('complete') }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Another one is:

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3]

const obs$ = nums.map((num, i) => {
  const promise = new Promise(resolve => resolve(num))
  return rxjs.from(promise).pipe(rxjs.delay(2000))
})

rxjs.concat(...obs$).subscribe(
  num => { console.log('next', num) },
  err => { console.error('error', err.message) },
  () => { console.log('complete') }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the code I've given is simplified code. In the real world this is an HTTP call whose response time is unknown. The setTimeout in my code is just mimicking an async op (i.e. the HTTP call) and thus this solution does not help me I'm afraid. I appreciate your time taken answering this though.

Comment: @danday74 Added one more solution. The promises are piped through. Whenever it gets completed it will complete 2 sec. later.

Comment: thanks again -  in relation to your 2nd suggested approach Timothy L Gillespie provided an almost identical answer and I have commented on that but that comment equally applies here - sadly it doesn't help again for similar reasons as your 1st suggested approach - however, your time attempting to answer is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a promise in this way seems to behave similar to debounce https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounce

Piping through a delay seems to do what you want, though. https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/delay

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3]

const obs$ = nums.map(num => {
  return rxjs.of(num).pipe(rxjs.delay(2000))
})

rxjs.concat(...obs$).subscribe(
  num => { console.log('next', num) },
  err => { console.error('error', err.message) },
  () => { console.log('complete') }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've got a feeling this doesn't help for the same reason as @Jai's answer - what I think this is doing is just delaying the beginning of the next Observable 2 secs instead of delaying the beginning of the next Observable until the previous one completes. In my simplified code, the setTimeout merely represent an async op and in real life is actually an HTTP call and this could take more or less than 2 secs to complete. Thanks for your time answering this though :)

Comment: Yes, I need them NOT to trigger at the same time though. I don't know what I am doing wrong. But I need them to trigger sequentially not all at the same time. Maybe concat is not the right approach but I don't know what the right approach is.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment after I realized the issue that you really meant. Didn't intend it to be a sneaky delete. I get now, though.

Answer (score 0):

**use `concatMap` and return your API (Promise)**

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3]

const api = (num) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(num), 2000));

rxjs.from(nums).pipe(
  rxjs.concatMap((n) => api(n))
).subscribe(
  num => { console.log('next', num) },
  err => { console.error('error', err.message) },
  () => { console.log('complete') }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```